# Get all git commit messages by tag does not work for production tag

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to retrieve a list of commits since the last commit with tag `production`. Given the following commits:

```
cd45ab  Some message 7      
a43fe7  Some message 6      #2.1.2
c34cf9  Some message 5
2ef4f5  Some message 4      #2.1.1
ab43ac  Some message 3
63ba2c  Some message 2      #2.1.0 #production
be461d  Some message 1
```

And when using the command `git log 2.1.0..HEAD --pretty=format:"%s"`, I receive a list consisting of commit messages 2 up to and including 7, which is what I expected.

However, when using `git log production..HEAD --pretty=format:"%s"`, I receive an seemingly unfiltered list of commit messages including commit message 1 and hundreds of earlier commits.

As commit 2 is both tagged with `2.1.0` and `production`, I would have expected to be able to use the `production` tag as well. Would anyone know why this isn't working? My goal is to create a changelog of all the commits since the last commit tagged with `production`.

Comment: check if you don't have a *branch* named `production` : `git branch`, or any other ref that could interact in a weird way : `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" | grep production`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I performed the command you suggested and it returned `refs/tags/production`, which doesn't seem strange.

Comment: if you run `git log --oneline --graph`, do you see tags `2.1.0` and `production` where you expect them ?

Comment: That indeed returns a list where the production tag is way lower than expected, thanks! Which is strange, as I perform a `git fetch` onbeforehand and the `production` tag is still present on an older commit. Only checking out the project in a different directory gave me the expected result, although I'd rather not perform a full checkout for logging purposes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spotted your first issue : your local `production` tag is not up to date.

---

It looks like you use a moving tag to spot your `production` commit. By default, most git commands will not overwrite your local tags, so a simple `git fetch` will not auto update your local copy of `refs/tags/production`.

You can explicitly force fetch it :

```
git fetch --force origin production
git fetch --force --tags    # this one will force update all your local tags
```

you can also add a refspec to instruct git to do it on every `git fetch` :
in the `.git/config`, spot the section `[remote "origin"]`, and add an extra line

```
fetch = +refs/tags/production:refs/tags/production
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Forcing the tag update resulted in `t [tag update]        production -> production`.

Comment: This is one (of several) reasons that it's not wise to move tags around. Branch names are *expected* to move; tag names are *not*. They both work to specify commits, but the expectations for the *names' behavior* differ.